# How do I expand table size so it would fill white space?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to fill white space between photo and promotion table with red color. 
I have tried to edit the code (showed bellow), but I can't figure out how to expand table size to the left, so it would be next to the photo:

```
        .how-it-works p {
    line-height: 21px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.hiw-side-promo {
    background-color: #EE4141;
    color: {{ settings.color_body_text }};
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-left: 28px;
    padding-right: 141px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 5px solid {{ settings.color_form_border }};
}
.hiw-side-promo .heading h3 {
    font-family: {{ settings.face_secondary_heading }};
    color: #fff;
}

.hiw-side-promo .paragraph {
    font-family: {{ settings.face_body_text }};
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.hiw-side-promo button {
    color: {{ settings.color_body_text }};
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: {{ settings.face_body_text }};
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: none;
}
```

This is a photo of how it looks now:

[image]

The white space between photo and table should be red.

Comment: we need to see some HTML and a working example on something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: please show html code tooo.. anyway have u tried  padding-left:ypx;where y = number of pixel

Comment: @Phoenix I tried to change "padding-left" pixel, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @mborg that's not actually much better - the problem is that once the site is fixed the question becomes meaningless and serves no purpose to future users - plus, JSFiddle is a very nice debugging environment - the act of creating a reduced example in JSFiddle will often show where the problem is

Comment: @mbord please show your html code..

Comment: @ToniLeigh Makes sense, I have created JSFiddle file: https://jsfiddle.net/u28y52eg/3/

Comment: Stack Overflow has a "jsfiddle"-lite functionality built into the editor to handle this, because many people don't have access to JSFiddle at work, and jsfiddle.net has been known to go down. The icon to the right of the image button starts the snippet editor.